# Простой способ визуализации в СИ

Tags: c, графика, 3d

Каким образом можно визуализировать результат работы программы, вычисляющей и возвращающей координаты точек в трехмерном пространстве? Данные такого вида:

```
Xn,Yn,Zn
```

,где n - координаты.
В общем мне нужно визуализировать геометрические фигуры, состоящие из массива точек и проверить правильность расчетов.

Comment: Если речь идет именно о 3д, то вряд ли вы сможете обойтись без какого-нибудь DirectX или OpenGL. Поэтому, собственно, и вопрос: а вы уверены, что вам точно нужно визуализировать точки в чистом Си?

Comment: на данный момент достаточно даже визуализации из текстового файла. В Си, в таком случае, будут только расчеты.

Comment: Сразу скажу -- не пробовал, но м.б. стоит взглянуть на [Tcl3D Overview](http://www.tcl3d.org/). Собственно, из Си, надеюсь как обычно, можно будет связаться с процессом через pipe и гнать туда свои координаты

Answer (score 6):

Если условие задачи допускает использование внешнего просмотрщика, то возьмите бесплатную программу визуализации 3D данных и выводите из вашей программы данные в ее формате. Например, "стандарт индустрии" [ParaView](https://www.paraview.org/).

Comment: GnuPlot вроде тоже неплох

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать библиотеку [GLUT](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "glut.h"  

//подключение библиотек импорта (используются директивы, специфичные для MS Visual C++)
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glut32.lib")

//POINT3D - представляет точку в пространстве
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} POINT3D;

//SHAPE3D - представляет трехмерную фигуру
typedef struct {
    POINT3D* points; //массив вершин
    int count_points; //число вершин
} SHAPE3D;

SHAPE3D* shapes = NULL; //массив фигур для отображения
int n_shapes = 0; //количество фигур

void DrawShapes(SHAPE3D* shapes, int n_shapes) //выводит массив фигур
{ 
 int i=0;
 int j=0;

 glBegin(GL_LINES);

 for(i=0; i<n_shapes; i++){
     for(j=0; j<shapes[i].count_points - 1; j++){
         glVertex3f(shapes[i].points[j].x,shapes[i].points[j].y,shapes[i].points[j].z); 
         glVertex3f(shapes[i].points[j+1].x,shapes[i].points[j+1].y,shapes[i].points[j+1].z); 
     }
 } 

 glEnd();
 glFlush();
}

void Draw(){
    DrawShapes(shapes,n_shapes);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //заполним массив тестовыми данными (2 грани куба)
    n_shapes = 2;
    shapes = (SHAPE3D*) malloc(sizeof(SHAPE3D) * n_shapes);

    shapes[0].count_points = 5;
    shapes[0].points = (POINT3D*) malloc(sizeof(POINT3D) * shapes[0].count_points);
    shapes[0].points[0].x = 0.0;
    shapes[0].points[0].y = 0.0;
    shapes[0].points[0].z = 0.0;
    shapes[0].points[1].x = 0.0;
    shapes[0].points[1].y = 1.0;
    shapes[0].points[1].z = 0.0;
    shapes[0].points[2].x = 1.0;
    shapes[0].points[2].y = 1.0;
    shapes[0].points[2].z = 0.0;
    shapes[0].points[3].x = 1.0;
    shapes[0].points[3].y = 0.0;
    shapes[0].points[3].z = 0.0;
    shapes[0].points[4].x = 0.0;
    shapes[0].points[4].y = 0.0;
    shapes[0].points[4].z = 0.0;

    shapes[1].count_points = 5;
    shapes[1].points = (POINT3D*) malloc(sizeof(POINT3D) * shapes[1].count_points);
    shapes[1].points[0].x = 0.0;
    shapes[1].points[0].y = 0.0;
    shapes[1].points[0].z = 0.0;
    shapes[1].points[1].x = 0.0;
    shapes[1].points[1].y = 0.0;
    shapes[1].points[1].z = 1.0;
    shapes[1].points[2].x = 1.0;
    shapes[1].points[2].y = 0.0;
    shapes[1].points[2].z = 1.0;
    shapes[1].points[3].x = 1.0;
    shapes[1].points[3].y = 0.0;
    shapes[1].points[3].z = 0.0;
    shapes[1].points[4].x = 0.0;
    shapes[1].points[4].y = 0.0;
    shapes[1].points[4].z = 0.0;

    //инициализация GLUT
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(600,400);      
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);    
    glutCreateWindow("Graphics");     

    //установка параметров камеры
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluPerspective( 40.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    gluLookAt(
        5.0, 5.0, 5.0,  //eye coordinates
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  //center coordinates
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0   //up direction
        );      

    //запуск цикла отрисовки
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);               
    glutMainLoop(); 

    free(shapes[0].points);
    free(shapes[1].points);
    free(shapes);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не тратить время на освоение низкоуровневых вещей, вроде `OpenGL`, можно воспользоваться какой-либо графической библиотекой. Таких библиотек имеется великое множество.

Для вывода 2D графики лично я использую либо `WinAPI GDI`, либо `SDL`.